# How to fix/calibrate mechanical thermostat that sometimes won't turn on heater?

Tags: thermostat, heater

In my house I have mechanical thermostats that control wall-mounted electric heaters. I have a couple of problems with these thermostats:

1. Sometimes they won't turn the heater on at all. Even if I put them at the max temperature. In this case, if I remove the cover and snap the piece of metal myself, the heater activates.
2. Sometimes I will have to turn them all they way to the max temperature for them to turn on.

I haven't been able to find the manual of instructions to see if I can calibrate or fix these thermostats, so my question is, is that possible to do? Or I need to change the thermostats altogether?

[image: Thermostat with cover removed]
[image: Thermostat]

Comment: You know there's 240 volts AC running around inside that thermostat, *right?* Sticking tools in there is a good way to get shocked to death or have an arc explosion in your face.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Thank you for your message! I won't be touching it, even with safe tools. I just learnt about arc explosion, yeah, I don't want that.

Do you happen to know how to fix this though?

Comment: @Nobita  replace them. they are at the end of their useful life and line voltage tstats are commonly available and not expensive.  No point in fiddling with a very old tstat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With electric heaters, there is a huge "perception" issue. Most of them are dead silent when energized, and take *quite some time* (several minutes) before you can feel heat at the registers.*  So you can't judge by feel. You need an indicator such as a pilot light or clamp ammeter around a wire.

However, these "line voltage" thermostats are cheap, in both senses of the word. They're not long-life performers, and also they are easy to replace.

So that may be the best plan, really - identify the existing wiring, choose a suitable replacement and have it swapped.

These thermostats do switch line voltage, so beware of shock hazards.  The circuit should be de-energized before any work of any kind is done.

---

---

---

* You may be wondering, "Wait. These are supposed to be 100% efficient by definition.  How can that be true, if power for the first few minutes *does nothing?* The answer is, it's just "thermal inertia" - it will keep making heat for a similar time after you turn it off, so you do get the heat you paid for.  *And no more*.

Comment: Thank you! I will check the wiring and buy whatever fits :)

Answer (score 0):

These thermostats probably have bi-metal contacts, maybe mercury and as such, the contacts get pitted or contaminated with slag from the arcing due to opening and closing. Manually opening and closing it can break away some of the impurities that are blocking the contacts from closing. You can turn off the power and clean the contacts with some emery paper. Depending on the age of them, you might want to get new ones from the manufacturer or from your home store. Just bring one of the old ones with (remember to turn off the power) and get a match.